# how to set vim map not change jumplist?

Tags: vim

```
[first line]

int test() {
    a   
    b
    c
    d
    {
        e
        f   
        g   
    }
}
```

1. The cursor in currently in line with `f`.
2. If I press `[[`, the cursor will go to `[first line]`.
3. I want cursor goto `int test() {`. So I set a mapping: `nnoremap [[ ][%`.
4. The map command works good, with one problem: if I press `CTRL+O`, cursor will go to the last line `}`.
5. What I want is the cursor to go back to the line with `f`.

I tried `nnoremap [[ :keepjumps normal ][%<CR>`, but it does not work.

How can I implement this?

1. press `[[` make cursor goto line with `int test(){`.
2. press `CTRL+O` make cursor jump back.

My vim version is Vi IMproved 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the jump list works is very often misunderstood. A jump, as stored in the jump list, only records the *origin* of the "jump" you made, not its destination. This means that `:help :keepjumps` is supposed to be used to prevent a new *origin* to be added to the jump list.

In order for `<C-o>` to jump back to the origin `f`, that origin must be present in the jump list so it's only the origin `}` that must be left out.

In doing:

```
nnoremap [[ :keepjumps normal ][%<CR>
```

you are effectively preventing *both* the origin `f` *and* the origin `}` to be added to the jump list.

You can fix your mapping by moving `][` out of the `:keepjumps` command:

```
nnoremap [[ ][:keepjumps normal %<CR>
```